# Yeoman vendor images paths are incorrect when building the application

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs, bower

I'm working on an AngularJS application with Yeoman.

The application depends on jQuery UI, which is installed with Bower. This is how I include the jQuery UI theme:

```
<!-- build:css styles/plugins.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.tooltip.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/jquery.ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When building the application, all goes well, without errors.

However, in the browser console (using Chrome), I can see that the images required by the jQuery UI Datepicker can't be found because it looks inside `styles/images/` and they actually are inside `components/...`.

**Screenshot**

[image: source image url]

My first idea was to override the jQuery UI image paths in CSS, but that doesn't seem like the best solution. Example:

**Original styling**

```
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png)/*{iconsError}*/;
}
```

**My override**

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
    background-image: url(../components/jquery.ui/themes/base/images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png);
}
```

Any recommended solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. But rather than changing the jQuery CSS (which could be harmful for future updates...), I just tweaked the "imagemin" task in the grunt script (Gruntfile.js) so that the images are copied where they are expected. This is true for any third party library as long as grunt takes care of modifying images pathes in the minified css.

Here is the change I made​​ (please note that my jQuery UI theme folder is located under the `app\styles` folder)

Before :

```
imagemin : {
    dist : {
        files : [{
                expand : true,
                cwd : '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src : '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After :

```
imagemin : {
    dist : {
        files : [{
                expand : true,
                cwd : '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src : '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }, {
                expand : true,
                flatten : true,
                cwd : '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                src : '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/images'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: It worked great for me, modifying the paths to distribute the images under 'bower_components'.

Comment: @Fernando Did you just change the styles directory to bower_components?

Comment: @grant, In my case, I copied all images under `app/bower_components` into `dist/styles/images`. Since the consolidated CSS is in `dist/styles`, this means that references to `images/someimage` in the CSS will work in the distribution package. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandoacorreia/11062046).

Comment: @FernandoCorreia I see, thank you. Though you have to do this manually after each build, correct?

Comment: @grant No. That code is in `Gruntfile.js`, which is grunt's configuration file. So every time I build for distribution (with the `grunt` command), the files are copied as per the configuration. During development, my `index.html` file references assets directly from the `bower_components` directory, within a `build:` tag so they get packaged by grunt.

Comment: I was running grunt-contrib-imagemin v0.9.2 and was getting `Fatal error: Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined` when I tried your solution. Upgrading to grunt-contrib-imagemin v1.0.0 fixed the issue. Cheers!

Comment: It just didn't  work for me. I am using generator-angular 0.15.1. I added `{
          expand : true,
          flatten : true,
          cwd : '/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/*/images',
          src : '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/images'
        }` But nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, I got it now: `{
            expand : true,
            flatten : true,
            cwd : 'bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/images',
            src : '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
            dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/images'
          }` BTW, flatten is not mandatory.